# Is it a bad practise if an XML node's content relies on a node attibute value?

Tags: xml

I need to describe queries in XML. A query clause consists of a value and a comparison type. For example, let's take three comparison types: equality, inclusion in a range and similarity, where an integer defines a degree of similarity. I can describe them like this:

```
<Clause type="equal">42</Clause>
<Clause type="inside" lowerlimit="41" upperlimit="43"/>
<Clause type="similar" degree="2">Abcd</Clause>
```

Or I can describe values in a context-specific node, like this:

```
<Clause type="equal">
  <Value>42</Value>
</Clause>

<Clause type="inside">
  <RangeLimit lowerlimit="41" upperlimit="43"/>
</Clause>

<Clause type="similar">
  <Similarity degree="2">Abcd</Similarity>
</Clause>
```

I find the first example to be more humanly readable, and the parser code will be more concise. There is also the fact that I have 9 types of clauses that take only the value (like equality), and only two that have additional parameters. So if I go with the second choice, the resulting XML will be severely larger, and size matters in the problem I'm solving.

On the other hand, I'm not sure I like the relation between attributes, and the second example is more descriptive and uniform.

Are there any possible implications for going with the first choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that depend on attributes are difficult to describe in a schema.

If you have to choose between the two you provided, the second one is easier to work with from a programming perspective. In either of the two, you wouldn't easily be able to constrain against mixing two forms of the `<Clause>` element:

```
<Clause type="similar">
    <RangeLimit lowerLimit="42" upperLimit="43"/>
</Clause>
```

Here are some alternatives:

```
<Equal>42</Equal>
<Inside lowerLimit="42" upperLimit="43"/>
<Similar degree="2">Abcd</Similar>

<Clause>
    <Similar degree="2">Abcd</Similar>
</Clause>
```